# Error Message in knockout at Magento Checkout

Tags: knockout.js, magento2

After navigating to checkout page I get the following error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function(){return setMethodsUi() }"
Message: setMethodsUi is not defined
    at text (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2992), <anonymous>:1:57)
    at update (knockout.js:4669)
    at ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:3383)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate_CallReadThenEndDependencyDetection (knockout.js:2183)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate_CallReadWithDependencyDetection (knockout.js:2150)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:2111)
    at Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.js:1964)
    at knockout.js:3381
    at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.js:159)
    at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:3353)
```

Your help will be highly appreciated. I have tried clearing cache, redeploy static content but no luck.

Comment: can you add the checkout page error suspected code? setMethodsUi is  not added in the scope

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know Magento but I have two comments: 1 - Knockout is telling you that `setMethodsUi` isn't known at that level/context of the view-model. Does it perhaps exist on a parent or child object? 2 - I don't think you need to wrap `setMethodsUi` in a `function() {...}` statement; I think you can declare the binding as `text: setMethodsUi()`. And depending on what `setMethodsUi` is/does you might not even need the invocation operator (the parentheses). But again, your function is not being found where Knockout expects to find it.

Comment: @GoodSamaritan sorry, I didn't get you

Comment: Please add your source also

Comment: @GoodSamaritan you can simply test it on https://booking24.pk by placing a simple order and on check out order you will see this error on inspecting element